# Loop in until parent value is null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have two tables, `tbl_folder`:

```
FOLDER_ID  FOLDER_NAME  PARENT_FOLDER_ID
1           Folder1
2           Folder1.1        1
3           Folder1.2        1
4           Folder1.1.1      2
5           Folder1.1.2      2
6           Folder1.2.1      3
7           Folder1.2.2      3
```

And `tbl_file`:

```
FILE_ID   FILE_NAME   PARENT_FOLDER_ID    ACTIVITY_ID
1         Abc.txt            5                2
2         PQR.txt            2                1
3         XYZ.txt            7                2
```

I am passing `activity_id` as input to a procedure and from that I can get the `parent_folder_id` of all the files with for that activity ID. I want to get the full path of that parent folder using the data from `tbl_folder`.

For example if I pass 2 as `activity_id` then I will get two files:

1. `Abc.txt` - parent folder ID of file is 5
2. `XYZ.txt` - parent folder ID of file is 7

From `parent_folder_id` I will get the name of the folder e.g. `Folder1.1.2`.
I will pick that folder's `parent_folder_id` and get its name and parent, and so on. In the end I will generate path for `Abc.txt` as `Folder1\Folder1.1\Folder1.1.2`.

What is the right way to do this? Should I use a loop for it? Or a temporary table? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm) to get the full path for each folder:

```
select folder_id, sys_connect_by_path(folder_name, '/') as path
from tbl_folder
start with parent_folder_id is null
connect by parent_folder_id = prior folder_id;

 FOLDER_ID PATH                                   
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 /Folder1                                
         2 /Folder1/Folder1.1                      
         4 /Folder1/Folder1.1/Folder1.1.1          
         5 /Folder1/Folder1.1/Folder1.1.2          
         3 /Folder1/Folder1.2                      
         6 /Folder1/Folder1.2/Folder1.2.1          
         7 /Folder1/Folder1.2/Folder1.2.2
```

The [`sys_connect_by_path` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions183.htm) is doing the construction of the full path for you here.

And you can join your `tbl_file` to that to get the full path for each file:

```
select f.file_name, h.path
from tbl_file f
join (
  select folder_id, sys_connect_by_path(folder_name, '/') as path
  from tbl_folder
  start with parent_folder_id is null
  connect by parent_folder_id = prior folder_id
) h
on h.folder_id = f.parent_folder_id
where f.activity_id = 2;

FILE_NAME  PATH                                   
---------- ----------------------------------------
Abc.txt    /Folder1/Folder1.1/Folder1.1.2          
XYZ.txt    /Folder1/Folder1.2/Folder1.2.2
```

Or with backslashes and without a leading slash on the root folder, which can be removed with `ltrim()`, this is closer to your example in the question:

```
select f.file_name, ltrim(h.path, '\') as path
from tbl_file f
join (
  select folder_id, sys_connect_by_path(folder_name, '\') as path
  from tbl_folder
  start with parent_folder_id is null
  connect by parent_folder_id = prior folder_id
) h
on h.folder_id = f.parent_folder_id
where f.activity_id = 2;

FILE_NAME  PATH                                   
---------- ----------------------------------------
Abc.txt    Folder1\Folder1.1\Folder1.1.2           
XYZ.txt    Folder1\Folder1.2\Folder1.2.2
```

In later versions of Oracle you could also use recursive subquery factoring, but that isn't available in 10g.